# Is Signature recreation will affect the functionality of my app?

Tags: robotium

I am newbie to Robotium. I started looking robotium and unfortunately it is working for me after a long struggle.

Can any one tell me that, since i have removed the dev signature and using my signature, will it affect the functionality of the app?

I heard that google maps only will be affected. Any more thoughts from any one?

Thanks
Chandra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android system uses the certificate as a means of identifying the author of an application and establishing trust relationships between applications.

No affect on functionality.

you need same signatures on apps those you use for automation test.

you will find more information on " http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html ", i hope you will get your answer here.
Thanks.